# Как работает метод класса Collections?

Tags: java, коллекции

Метод

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

Запутался, что происходит. Помогите понять:

`<T>` - дженерик ?

`List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>` тут что происходит ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<T>` - да это дженерик тип.

`List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>` - Лист объектов, которые реализуют интерфейс `Comparable` типизированные любым  предком `T` или самим `T`

Бинарному поиску нужен отсортированный список, поэтому он принимает список только тех объектов, которые известно как сортировать, реализация интерфейса `Comparable`.

Comment: Вас пытаются поправить - "любым предком T" . Посмотрите правку. У автора правки пока не хватает репутации написать комментарий.